# External js script won't work on pages loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to load html posts into my main html page and have external scripts work on them.

I have this script (load.js) to load posts into my index.html page:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#header').load("./Includes/include_header.html");
    $('#footer').load("./Includes/include_footer.html");
    $('#navbar').load("./Includes/include_navbar.html");

    // Posts
    $('#post3').load("./Posts/2021-11-16-Starting-Book-of-Shaders.html");
    $('#post2').load("./Posts/2021-11-12-Lecture-1.html");
    $('#post1').load("./Posts/2021-11-12-Start.html");
});
```

This works and I can get the posts on the page. But scripts that should be changing the "post load" html page won't work.

In my index.html's `<head>` I have this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/load.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/master/dist/GlslCanvas.js" defer></script>
```

but `GlslCanvas.js` won't recognize the `<canvas>` element inside my post (in this example "2021-11-16-Starting-Book-of-Shaders.html"):

```html
<div class="card">
    <h2>Getting started with The Book of Shaders</h2>
    <p>Testing the very first, most basic example:</p>
    <canvas class="glslCanvas" data-fragment-url="/Shaders/test.frag" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

`test.frag` file is composed of these few lines:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.8196, 0.7804, 0.2235, 1.0);
}
```

I have tried to include the line:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/master/dist/GlslCanvas.js" defer></script>
```

inside the posts as well, before and after the `<div>` but it makes no difference.

What should I do so that the script recognizes the `<canvas>` element?

Edit:
I can confirm it works by placing `<canvas class="glslCanvas" data-fragment-url="/Shaders/test.frag" width="400" height="400"></canvas>` directly inside the `<body>` of my index page. No problems there.

Comment: It is not clear if you have script in the included html.

Comment: Perhaps this https://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/issues/42

Comment: I think that link is talking about including other shaders in your code, not how to include the canvas in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    let deferreds = [];
    function load(selector, path) {
        const def = new $.Deferred()
        deferreds.push(def);
        $(selector).load(path, () => def.resolve());
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        load('#header', "./Includes/include_header.html");
        load('#footer', "./Includes/include_footer.html");
        load('#navbar', "./Includes/include_navbar.html");

        // Posts
        load('#post3', "./Posts/2021-11-16-Starting-Book-of-Shaders.html");
        load('#post2', "./Posts/2021-11-12-Lecture-1.html"),
        load('#post1', "./Posts/2021-11-12-Start.html")
            
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() { 
            var list = document.getElementsByClassName('glslCanvas');
            
            if (list.length > 0) {
                window.glslCanvases = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var sandbox = new GlslCanvas(list[i]);
                    if (sandbox.isValid) {
                        window.glslCanvases.push(sandbox);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

### main page code:

[image]

### loading page code (load.html):

[image]

### result:

[image]

Comment: I had to remove the parenthesis at the end of your function and then call it to not get any erros, like this: `loadAllGlslCanvas();`

But it still doesn't work

Comment: Try to remove defer in GlslCanvas connection string

Comment: Just tried it, no luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you add `console.log(list);` after the `var list = document.getElementsByClassName('glslCanvas');`, is the list printed to the console?

Comment: It does! It returns the number of glslCanvases I have on the page correctly.

Comment: Can you share a fragment of test.frag ?

Comment: test.frag is just 9 lines: `#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;

void main() {
 gl_FragColor = vec4(0.8196, 0.7804, 0.2235, 1.0);
}`

And I know it works because I have it running directly in the index's body. It just won't load from the inserted html

Comment: Let's do it like this - fixed

Comment: But it's not fixed though, it still won't run the scripts on the canvases if I load them through the functions described in my question

Comment: It worked for me. The essence of the code is that it waits for the content to load through the load functions and then processes the GlslCanvas

Comment: I've noticed the updated answer. I now get the error: `jQuery.Deferred exception: GlslCanvas is not defined ReferenceError: GlslCanvas is not defined`

Comment: Place the script connection `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/master/dist/GlslCanvas.js"></script>` immediately after connecting jQuery (note that there is no defer)

Comment: No errors now, but still not working. When I do `console.log(deferreds);` it returns an empty array

Comment: As I already asked - give the code of one of your shaders on which you are trying. Add the complete shader code to your question

Comment: Ok, sorry. I've added the shader code to the question.

Comment: added my working simple (images)

Comment: It's working perfectly now! Thank you very much!